# Uncertainty Calculation when measurements are subject to a constraint

Tags: normalization, measurement-error, uncertainty

#### I would like to know how to properly propagate the errors on measurements where I know a constraint on the sum of these measurements.

Lets say I have a rod of length exactly 1 metre which I have drawn lines across to mark it into 10 sections. I also have an instrument which can tell me the relative distance between each of the segments along with an uncertainty for these.

These measurements might be represented by something like this in python

```
import numpy as np
# A series of relative measurements and their uncertainties
x = np.random.uniform(size=10)
dx = np.random.uniform(size=10)*x
```

Where x is the series of relative measurements and dx is the series of uncertainties.

Since I know the length of the rod is 1 metre, I can normalise the values of x (which was on a relative scale) so that the sum of the sizes of all the segments is the length of the rod.

```
x_in_metres = x/x.sum()
```

I want to know how I should scale the size of my uncertainties, dx, using this information. Initially I was thinking that they would just scale like

```
dx_in_metres = dx/x.sum()
```

but I am not sure if this fully utilizes the information that the length of the rod is 1. I think this extra information brings in some correlations that I am not taking account of.

Can someone point me in the right direction?